# HLS in VideoView freezes my Android app while seeking

Tags: android, android-videoview, http-live-streaming, android-anr-dialog

I have a problem seeking HLS (.m3u8) playlist on native VideoView.

I've built an Activity that when pressing on ImageView it opens up a new Activity via Intent and start playing an HLS video using native VideoView (I'm aware of the issues with HLS on Android) but when going back to Activity A after seeking in Activity B, Activity A freezes GUI for approx. 30 seconds (When pressing on UI element in Activity A, I see ANR) and then it "release" the GUI again.

Problem is when I try to use :

```
mVideoView.seekTo(position);
mVideoView.start()
```

UI in Activity B seems OK, video will not seek actually freezes and when I back pressed I get this:

LogCat:

```
Shutting down current MediaPlayer
System.out﹕ Close in OkHttp
[CDS]close[41023]
[CDS][DNS] getAllByNameImpl netId = 0
[getaddrinfo]: hostname=31.168.5.3; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null),     netid=0; mark=0
[getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
[CDS]rx timeout:60000
[socket][3] connection /31.168.5.3:8089;LocalPort=47817(0)
[CDS]connect[/31.168.5.3:8089] tm:90
ANR Key Analyze: No Key event currently.
ANR Key Analyze: Previeous Event null,finish at 1970-01-01 02:00:00.000`
```

And After approx. 30 seconds:

```
[CDS]EAGAIN in Recvfrom
[CDS]read byte is 0
surfaceDestroyed callback -, this =             com.brightcove.player.view.BrightcoveSurfaceView{8b5c8c0 V.E..... ........ 0,8-1280,728}
Layout: x=0 y=8 w=1280 h=720, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1280, 720), this =     com.brightcove.player.view.BrightcoveSurfaceView{8b5c8c0 V.E..... ........ 0,8-    1280,728}
```

It looks as if the connection when setting Video Uri is keeping a connection open and only a timeout releases it or something like this.
It happens only on one device, Lenovo 7-inch Tablet with OS 5.0 (Lollipop), on other it does not happen.

Also, when playing regular mp4 streams I didn't encounter this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Found any solution for this issue ? I have the same exact problem with the same device.